# Run a query multiple times with same values

Tags: c#

I'm using c# and trying to insert into sql same query multiple times:
  Here is my code:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new  SqlCommand ("insert into InventoryTransTemp (name) values ('test')",con);
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

How can i run this same query example 5 times??

Can i use a string for doing this? Example if string count=5 then run query 5 times

Comment: You need [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql)

Comment: Can i use a number in a string for making this? Example if string count=5 then insert it 5 times. Something like that

Comment: use a `for` loop and parse the string variable for the maximum amount of times

Comment: Do you mean you loop? Or do you want to create an insert statement that inserts values repeatedly into the table? It is unclear what you are actually asking for.

Comment: I found this but i dont understand the code very much.Can i use something more simple? https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic911157-338-1.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert multiple rows with a single `INSERT` command by separating your parenthesis-enclosed row data with commas. So you can create a loop for the number of rows you want to add, and then add the row data values (and a comma) to your query string on each iteration:

```
var queryString = "INSERT INTO InventoryTransTemp ([name]) VALUES ";
var rowData = "('test')";
int numRows = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
{
    queryString += rowData;
    if (i < numRows - 1) queryString += ", ";
}

// At this point, query string looks like:
// "INSERT INTO InventoryTransTemp ([name]) VALUES ('test'), ('test'), ('test'), ('test'), ('test')"

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specific query, you can use in the method. Maybe firstly you should search how many same string is counted like this:

```
public void run() {
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into InventoryTransTemp (name) values ('test')", con);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}


public int findString() {
  int i = 0;
  SqlDataReader stRead = new sqlCommand("SELECT * FROM database ", con);
  while (stRead.Read()) {
    i++;
  }
  return i;
}
int i = findString();
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
  run();
}
```